# how to validate data from generated form and grid in c# winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, data-binding, datagridview

so i am following [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/SamTomato/database-table-update-in-a-datagridview-without-writing-code/).

i want to validate the data and give nicer error report, because the current error report looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fHGq.png)

what i want is to give error in cell using `cell.ErrorText` not the `MessageBox`.

thanks for answering.

Comment: i dont know where to put the error provider control, i have try following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ehy30d4(v=vs.110).aspx) but it do not work.  what i want is how to catch the error so the messageBox do not show up

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the validation you want to do you can use the `CellValueChanged` event handler or the `CellValidated` event handler then perform the validation check you want on the current cell and modify its `cell.ErrorText` message